# Why shouldn't I use a chunk in a tasklet?

Tags: spring-batch

The [Spring Batch documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#taskletStep) says:

> no `<chunk/>` element should be used within the `<tasklet/>`

There is no further explanation and I can't imagine any. Can anybody please explain this limitation to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have missed something.

This piece of document is saying that, `no <chunk/> element should be used within the <tasklet/>` IF you are configuring for a Tasklet step.

If you look around a bit, you will see, in order to configure a chunk-oriented step, you are in fact using `<chunk/>` within a `<tasklet/>`

Comment: Hm, I think I got it. The concept of a _pure_ tasklet step excludes the use of chunks, because chunks should apply readers and writes whereas pure tasklets do a simple operation (the doc mentions a stored procedure call as an example). So I think, I just misunderstood the quote. Thanks for enlightening me ;-)

Comment: @PeterWippermann it is mostly correct.  To be more precise, in fact Tasklet allow you to develop logic that invokes in multiple iteration, each under separate transaction.  Chunk-oriented (Reader-Writer) and Simple once-off tasklet are just two obvious usages.